# error on second pass through loop copying data from oracle to excell

Tags: excel, loops, oracle-sqldeveloper, recordset, vba

I am a very occasional amature when it comes to vba but I would have thought this should be straight forward?

I am trying to copy the contents of each table in an oracle db into separate tabs in an excel file.  The code gets the names of the tables I want from a list in the first tab of the excel file and puts them in an array.  I am then trying to loop through the array, creating a new tab for each table and copying the data across.  The code works for the first pass through the For Each loop but always fails at the point where it tries to open the rs for the 2nd table.  I have tried various arrangements of the recordset opening and closing inside and outside the loop to no avail.  If I don't close the rs after copying the data across I get an error saying its not closed when it gets to the rs.Open (sSQL), con line, if I do close the connection I get an unspecified error at the same point....

```
Sub Ora_Connection()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim query As String            ' a string to contain the db connection data
Dim myTABLELIST As Variant         ' a variant to contain the list of oracle tables that contain data that we want to copy to excel
Dim lArr As Variant


' copy contents of TABLELIST into vb array
myTABLELIST = Worksheets("TABLE_LIST").ListObjects("TABLELIST").DataBodyRange.Value


' add a tab for every table in list
For Each lArr In myTABLELIST

        ' connect to oracle db
        Set con = New ADODB.Connection
         con.CursorLocation = adUseClient ' avoid error 3705 - doesn't do anything
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        '---- Replace HOST and COONECT_DATA with values for the db you are connecting to
        strCon = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
        "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
        "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
        "(HOST=myHost)(PORT=1521))" & _
        "(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mySID))); uid=myUID; pwd=myPWD;"
        '---  Open   the above connection string.
        con.Open (strCon)
        '---  Now connection is open and you can use queries to execute them.
        '---  It will be open till you close the connection

        ' make the connection able to travel only forwards through the recordset, so the query runs faster
        rs.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly



    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = lArr

    'creat SQl statement that uses table name in array
    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & lArr
    'If Not rs.State = adStateClosed Then
    'MsgBox "The recordset is already open"
    'End If
    rs.Open (sSQL), con
    Worksheets(lArr).Activate
    ' copy column header from source data into row 1
    For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
     ActiveSheet.Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next
    ' copy all data rows from source data into range starting at A2
    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
     ActiveSheet.Cells(1, rs.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs


Next lArr



' clear recordset and close connection
Set rs = Nothing
Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: please remove all the commented code. It (seems) useless to the question and makes it very hard to read. I also suggest removing your Oracle connection string information from the post.

Comment: I copied your code exactly (changed only the connection information) into Excel version 14.0.7015.1000, added a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library, created a "TABLE_LIST" worksheet with a "TABLELIST" table with 2 rows and it ran fine. Extracted all data from my two tables into the created worksheets.

Comment: Sorry about the commented code - I was just trying to show what I had tried before.  My excel is 14.0.7184.5000 - can't see that being the issue? I'm also using the same vba reference you refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Sub Ora_Connection()

    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim myTABLELIST As Variant, strCon As String, iCols As Long
    Dim lArr As Variant, ws As Worksheet, r As Long, wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    myTABLELIST = wb.Worksheets("TABLE_LIST").ListObjects("TABLELIST").DataBodyRange.Value

    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    strCon = "yourConnectionInfoHere"
    con.Open strCon

    ' add a tab for every table in list
    For r = 1 To UBound(myTABLELIST, 1)

        lArr = myTABLELIST(r, 1)

        Set rs = con.Execute("SELECT * FROM " & lArr)
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
        ws.Name = lArr
        For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            ws.Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
        Next
        ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, rs.Fields.Count).Font.Bold = True
        If Not rs.EOF Then ws.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    Next r

    Set rs = Nothing
    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it seems to get to the same point as my code: first tab created and populated ok, but then fails at the 2nd iteration round the outer loop at this step:  'Set rs = con.Execute("SELECT * FROM " & lArr)' - with Unspecified Error...

Comment: Are you sure that table/view exists and you have read access to it?  If you move that to the top of the list does it fail in the first iteration?

Comment: Yes, I had the same thought, I reversed the order of the tables in the list and it made no difference.  I also tried moving the loop code to another module so that I was definitely closing the recordset and connection and setting them to nothing between loops but it still fails at the 2nd attempt to open the recordset...

Comment: I just double checked your suggestion about there being a problem with the 2nd table, I think I used my old code when I reversed the table order and it still failed.  When I reversed the table order with your code it now works! A closer inspection of the 2nd table revealed that it had a BLOB field and it was probably that which was causing my problem all along... many thanks to you and TurtlesAllTheWayDown and  Scott Holtzman for perservering with me.